# Create a script that adds lines of code to .bashrc then reloads the terminal

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a shell script that once run, adds a line of code to the end of .bashrc then reloads the terminal. This is the code i have written in my install.sh

```
function addbashaliases() {
  echo 'if [ -f ~/aliases/.bash_aliases ]; then
          . ~/aliases/.bash_aliases
        fi' >> ~/.bashrc;
  source ~/.bashrc
}
```

Nothing is happening. How should I write the code so that it runs and adds the text to the .bashrc file?

Comment: So what is not working?

Comment: do not forget to actually call the function you have defined

Comment: `adds a line of code to the end of ` what line of code? you are not trying to do anything like that in your script. You are just checking whether .bash_aliase file available if available you just run it and ouput to .bashrc.

Comment: Why would you want a function to append that line instead of just appending it? Surely it will only ever be used once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of clarity I prefer to append the information on the `.bashrc` file using the `cat` command instead of the `echo`. However, this should work also using your `echo` command.

This said you should make sure that:

- The script calls the `addbashaliases` function
- The `~/aliases/.bash_aliases` file exists (I would expect to have something more similar to `~/.aliases/.bash_aliases`)

You can check that the script has correctly run by checking the content of the ~/.bashrc file and printing some environment variable set on the `.bash_aliases` file after the `source` command.

```
#!/bin/bash

function addbashaliases() {
  # Add source bash_aliases on .bashrc
  cat >> ~/.bashrc << EOT
if [ -f ~/aliases/.bash_aliases ]; then
  . ~/aliases/.bash_aliases
fi
EOT

  # Reload current environment
  source ~/.bashrc
}

# Execute the function                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
addbashaliases
```

Answer (score 1):

I am just correcting your script. As per your logic it should be like below.

```
function addbashaliases() {
   if [ -f ~/aliases/.bash_aliases ]; then
      output=$(. ~/aliases/.bash_aliases)
      echo $output >> ~/.bashrc
   fi
  source ~/.bashrc
}
```